# Why does Tmux have a server? Whats the benefit?

Tags: shell, server, client, daemon, tmux

Im fairly new to Tmux but from what I've read, its using a client-server connection.

Why is that neccessary? Is that only for managing sessions? Why does it communicate through a socket rather than directly with the client?

If anyone could provide me an explanation, that would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Not a programming question - try [su] ?

Comment: I imagine it does relate to programming because im basically asking why it helps the code to have a server. I guess i was wrong.

Comment: For info about what sort of questions are on-topic please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tmux requires a server that is able to keep located the processes when a session is detached.

If you run a process with the "nohup" or "disown" the process in going to run in background even when user logout, however the problem is to recover the control of the process when the user login again.

Tmux server keep those processes associated, so when you login and the user attach the session again. Tmux server is able to MUltipleX several Terminal sessions among other things.

All the magic of Tmux in made by the server, but you don't have to be afraid of Tmux server because, the Tmux server is not running as a general system daemon, the Tmux server is launched from the userspace individually, and when not user sessions are allocated Tmux server automatically stop itself, this is the reason why when you type "tmux ls" and sessions were not previously created the message "failed to connect to server: Connection refused" is displayed (The server is not running, hereby connection is refused).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Basically answered my question that the server is only there to remember the sessions.