# How to keep tmux session alive even the main terminal windows is closed?

Tags: session, tmux

My goal is to keep a `tmux` session alive even the main terminal windows is closed. I wonder would it be possible?

---

When I close the main terminal window tmux session ends but if I close single windows with in the terminal it does not.

If there is two or multiple windows or tabs, and when I close one of it session still continues and nothing happens. But when I close the last remaining window within the session it will terminate the on going tmux session.

Possible cases, while the terminal is open that has the tmux session remotely connected using ssh; and if I close the iTerm2 with the close circle on the top left part my on going tmux session is terminated.

Example screen-view:

```
❯ which goo
goo: aliased to ssh -xt4C user@IP
```

[image]

---

I have been told that on [iTerm2 issues](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/9731#note_599943069):

> What you're closing are window panes, not windows. If you close the last window pane it detaches because tmux automatically detaches when there are no more window panes left. This is consistent with tmux's behavior outside tmux integration. I don't believe tmux has a way to disable this behavior, although it would not be unreasonable to ask for such a change (this would need to be done by tmux, and I could later add support for it)

---

My `tmux` configuration:

[image]

Comment: I'm probably misunderstanding, but I think what you want is the default behavior of tmux (I don't have iTerm2 available and I don't know how it interferes). I can't really follow your gif. Are we talking about these steps? 1. Open a new terminal emulator. 2. Start a tmux session using `tmux` (and maybe start something inside it). 3. Close the terminal emulator window, using the GUI close button. 4. Now, the tmux server hosting the session should still be running. You should be able to 5. Open a new terminal emulator window, and, using `tmux a`, get back to your session.

Comment: @He3lixxx Yes sir. Maybe after step 3. we can restart the computer as well. When I do those after step 3 and re-try to connect to tmux session it was ended.

Comment: Obviously, restarting only works when your tmux session is somewhere remote. On your machine, the tmux server is shut down when you restart. Apart from that, what I described is the default behavior of tmux. [It will have that background server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42613371/12345551). If you close the last window, it seems like iTerm2 is supposed to ask you whether you want to [detach or to kill the session](https://medium.com/@gveloper/using-iterm2s-built-in-integration-with-tmux-d5d0ef55ec30). You should [be able to re-attach after that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/174440).

Comment: In your gitlab bug report, you posted a console log. There, it says "detached", which is exactly what we would expect. Also, after reading the bug report, I think there is a misunderstanding -- it seems to me that George thinks you want tmux to detach, but that the iTerm window should stay open. From how I understood you, you want the session to detach and the window to close. I seems to me this is also what George expects to happen.

Comment: Are you sure the session is killed? Maybe iTerm just does not automatically re-attach, or creates a new session instead of re-attaching, after reconnecting? I don't know how passing commands through to tmux in iTerm works, but in vanilla tmux, you should be able to see all sessions running in tmux if you press prefix+s.

Comment: I am sure that it is killed, I have check multiple times. Like if the iTerm2 is force to close and re-opened all the tmux sessions that are created using iTerm2 is ended. Please also note that I am creating tmux sessions on the remotely connected nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Latest quote from George Nachman in your Gitlab issue](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/9731#note_616915534):

> Depends if the close button is bound to hide the window or kill the window. If it's set to kill then you would not be able to get the window back by reattaching

So, it seems like you simply want the button to be bound to hide the window. As I said in a comment, by default, iTerm2 should ask you what you want to do:

[image: iTerm2 Confirmation Dialog when closing a tmux window]

If you ever checked "remember my choice" here and clicked kill, this is what iTerm2 does for you now.

I couldn't find any entry on where to reset this in the documentation, but there was [this google groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/g/iterm2-discuss/c/rrcj-wtsAEc) where George said:

> There's a prompt which shows by default but can be permanently suppressed. If you'd like it back, turn off Prefs > Advanced > Suppress kill/hide dialog when closing a tmux tab. There's another similarly named advanced pref for tmux windows.

The discussion is from 2018, but [this option can still be found in the code](https://github.com/gnachman/iTerm2/blob/master/sources/iTermAdvancedSettingsModel.m#L528), so I'd assume it's still there.

So, you probably want to disable Preferences > Advanced > Suppress kill/hide dialog when closing a tmux window.

Comment: I was not able to find the Warning window using `Preferences > Advanced > Suppress kill/hide dialog `. Please also see my tmux configuration on my updated question.

Comment: The screenshot you posted shows iTerm's `General` preferences, not the `Advanced` ones. In the preferences window, at the top, there should be categories ("General", "Appearance", "Profiles", "Keys", "Arrangements", "Pointer", "Advanced"). Click on `Advanced`. It should look like [this](https://images3.programmersought.com/518/4d/4d9276a28dfb4de01f5bd3b4c3ab9716.png). Enter `tmux` in the search bar. There should be the option `Suppress kill/hide dialog when closing a tmux window`.

Comment: Interesting I can only see following options, where `Suppress kill/hide dialog when closing a tmux window` does not exits https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/944e6efbdabbf942883924ff082d23f2#gistcomment-3801645  . Please note that I am using iTerm2 nighly build == https://iterm2.com/downloads/nightly/#/section/home

Comment: The screenshot - again - only lists the options from "Preferences > General", so I will assume that you executed the search from that location. The last entry, named "Advanced Preferences...", also indicates that entries from Advanced Preferences are not listed, but could be accessed if you selected this option.

Comment: After the `hide` is done I am seeing followin window when I re-try to attach https://gist.github.com/avatar-lavventura/944e6efbdabbf942883924ff082d23f2#gistcomment-3802917  I was not able to make it re-attach itself tho.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `nohup` command to launch tmux? I generally use this command whenever I want to launch a program from a shell in Linux and I don't want that program to be terminated when I close the terminal emulator I launched it from. E.g. to launch a PDF reader called `zathura` I would use something like `nohup zathura file.pdf &` and then I can close the terminal emulator without `zathura` closing as well. Hopefully this could work for you on macOS too.

Comment: While this works for other programs, I don't see how it would help with tmux. `tmux`, when first executed, starts two processes: a server and a client. Only the client is bound to the tty. It will exit when receiving sighup, which is what we want. This should not affect the server: we should be able to reattach to the session using `tmux a`. Using nohup would cause the client to not exit when it should.

Comment: @Andrea B.  How do you start tmux inside a nohup process? like `nohup tmux a &`?